# the problem statement but I don't know what exactly is indented

Tags: python, list, while-loop, indentation

Increment the variable num by 1 post checking the above condition. (note that this increment will be outside the if statement, take care of the indentation in order to avoid a scenario of infinite loop)

this is the problem statement but I don't know what exactly is indented

I don't know if its correct or not

```
num = 1
factors=[ ]

while num <= 100: 

    if (num % 10) == 0 :

    factors.append(num)

    num += 1 

    print(factors)
```

Comment: So the issue is your not sure how to indent that? Whats your expected output?

Comment: using a while loop to iterate over natural numbers from 1 to 100 and store only the multiples of 10 in a list and print that list .
THIS IS THE PROBLEM STATEMENT

Comment: Okay then my solution should work for you, thats the result i got when i ran it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer to your question

```
num = 1
factors = []
while num <= 100:
    if (num % 10) == 0:
        factors.append(num)
    num += 1
print (factors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation to indicate nested blocks of code, in this example you have a block of code within your `while` loop, indicated by the 4 space indentation. You then have an `if` statement when then also needs it's content indented by another 4 spaces. This would give you the following result:

```py
num = 1
factors = []

while num <= 100: 
    if (num % 10) == 0:
        factors.append(num)
        num += 1 

print(factors)
```

Comment: I don't whats the issue but it didn't execute but below code executed .anyways  thank you 


num = 1
factors = []

while num <= 100: 
    if (num % 10) == 0:
        factors.append(num)
        num += 1 

print(factors)